# eas build android fails due to com.facebook.react.module.annotations missing

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo

I recently updated to expo SDK 44 and now I'm getting below error when trying to build for android using eas-cli. Any ideas on why?

```
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
[stderr] /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java:27: error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist
[stderr] import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
[stderr]                                             ^
[stderr] /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
[stderr] @ReactModule(name = AsyncStorageModule.NAME)
[stderr]  ^
[stderr]   symbol: class ReactModule
[stderr] Note: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[stderr] Note: /root/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[stderr] 2 errors
> Task :react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
[stderr] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 4m 31s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
204 actionable tasks: 204 executed
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I change `"expo": "^44.0.0"` to `"expo": "~44.0.0"`

and `"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0"`.